# Export notes as a (high quality) pdf

Tags: pdf, notes.app

I want to export a note as a pdf, but the option "export as a pdf" in the Notes app generates a poor quality pdf. Is there some solution for this, or perhaps a third party software able to control the quality of the output pdf file?

Comment: What's in the Note? Regular text saves like any vector graphic - you can enlarge it to infinity without it ever becoming pixellated.

Comment: handwriten text with the apple pencil

Comment: OK, never used that so can't really help. Presumably it's saving as raster not vector, so you'd first need to figure out whether the original note is raster or vector. Vector, like text, is infinitely scaleable; raster starts life as pixels so there's a finite limit as to how it translates to other sizes. Basically, if it's saving the pdf as "a picture" then see if there's any other option. Provide an example file if you can - to dropbox or somewhere we can examine it.

Comment: Would you be willing to let us know what version and OS of notes app you’re using with an edit and what specifically defines low quality? Perhaps upload a sample of this file to pastebin or other?

Comment: I'm trying IOS 15, and BigSur on the macbook. I cannot read my own text. It seems a poorly rasterized bitmap

Comment: A bitmap ***is*** a raster. What do you see if you zoom the original note? Does it become pixellated eventually, or stay 'smooth'? I tested a text drawn by finger on iPhone then exported as pdf from the Mac - no matter how far I blow it up, it stays reasonably clean, though not perfect - https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1rGZ.png

Comment: I also obtain reasonable results for short notes, but not for long ones.

Comment: I get same result as @Tetsujin.  Can you please post an example which shows your problem.